# Manipulating a log normal variable

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus

I am wondering given:

[image]

and

[image]

is it possible to state:

$$\text{Jdq}_t s_t-\text{dq}_t s_t=\text{dq}_t \log (J) s_t$$

And if it is the case can we show how this argument is done?

Comment: If $dS_t=(J-1)S_t\,dq_t$, then $d\log(S_t)=\log(J)dq_t$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Would you be able to provide me with some resources so that I could have a look at this.